# How to work with windows based pop ups on Mac System

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, selenium-webdriver, popup

How to work with windows based pop ups on Mac System.Since AutoIT doesn't work on mac either.I have Xcode application in My laptop.I read something about Applescript as equivalent for AutoIt .But I couldn't find it anywhere.

I am trying to automate download popups using selenium web driver and eclipse .I know how to work with robot API and now i am looking for AUTOIT equivalent for Mac laptop

Answer (score 1):

Try with apple script Please find the below which will be helpful.

https://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-ultimate-beginners-guide-to-applescript--mac-3436

You can execute apple script through command Using Runtime Execution Concept in Java